# Representation of weak*-continuous linear functionals on a subspace which is not necessarily weak* closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $X^{*}$ be its dual space. Let $M$ a subspace of $X^{*}$ on which a weak*-continuous linear functional $L$ is given. In the case where $M$ is weak*-closed, we know that there exists an element $x\in X/{M}_\perp$ which represents $L,$ *i.e.*, $$L(m)=m(x)\qquad (m\in M),$$ where $M_\perp$ denotes the pre-annihilaor of $M$ in $X.$ I have the following question;

> Is the conclusion above true even when $M$ is not necessarily weak*-closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend $L$ uniquely (by weak* continuity) to the weak*-closure of $M$. And the preannihilator of $M$ coincides with the preannihilator of its weak* closure.

Comment: No, I don't think we can extend. I mean if you choose net $\{\varphi_{\alpha}\}$ which converges to a $\varphi_0$ in weak* closure, how do we know that $\{L(\varphi_{\alpha})\}$ converges?

Comment: Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $L$ is weak* cts, we find a weak* neighborhood $V$ of $0$, such that $L(V\cap M) \subset (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. Since $\{\varphi_\alpha\}$ converges, there is $\gamma$ with $\varphi_\alpha - \varphi_\beta \in V$ for $\alpha, \beta \ge \gamma$. Hence, $L(\varphi_\alpha - \varphi_\beta) \subset (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. Hence, $\{L(\varphi_\alpha)\}$ is a Cauchy net and converges.